# I can't add data to chartjs from codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, chart.js, codeigniter-3

How can I encode json for $info['data'] in codeigniter framework

```
public function chartjs(){
        $info['title'] = 'Chartjs';
        $info['data'] = $this->post_model->get_posts();
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('chartjs',$info);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

// This Is edited Code for encode json for $info['data']

```
public function chartjs(){
        $info['title'] = 'Chartjs';
        $post_data = $this->post_model->get_posts();
        $info['data'] = json_encode($post_data);
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('chartjs',$info);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

*I am sure help of this code You can encode json correctly.*
Thanks,
**Kamiyab ali**